# Export Jar Application unable to connect with MySql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, jdbc

I made a swing application which is Database Inventory Management System, Tested on Eclipse and it is working fine, connecting with MySql and all other function. After I create Jar file using Export option in Eclipse, I am unable to connect with MySql Database. I think error is due to jdbc driver, Can anyone guide me what could be the possible issue, is there any specific way to create jar which all support database connection.

Comment: What exception you are getting..print it on console..

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your project as Runnable Jar.Right click on project,then export and export as runnable jar ,there you will have the option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".

Comment: my problem is resolved by exporting in runnable jar and then choosing option extract required libraries into generated jar ... Thanks for Help...